# Permission denied in copying the input file from local to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs, local, permission-denied

I am unable to put file into the HDFS. Whenever I try to execute `put` command, I receive a permission denied error. I have tried giving all read write execute permissions to the input file, but the problem still stands.

This is the command I executed. I am currently in `hduser` which has hadoop installed in it:

```
hadoop dfs -put /home/hduser/input /
```

The error I receive is the following:

> WARNING: Use of this script to execute dfs is deprecated. WARNING:
>   Attempting to execute replacement "hdfs dfs" instead. put:
>   /input._COPYING_ (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put) of the `put` command you should use it like the following:

```
hadoop fs -put /path/to/localfile /home/hduser/input
```

where:

1. `/path/to/localfile` is the path on local FS where is the file you want to put on HDFS
2. `/home/hduser/input`is the HDFS destination folder path